# Sorting the hexadecimal color code in vim

Tags: vim

I use Sass. I created a color palette that looks like this:

```
$palette-cerebralGray: #cccccc;
$palette-black: #000000;
$palette-read: #202020;
$palette-gravelFint: #bbbbbb;
$palette-tombBlue: #009acd;
$palette-basaltGray: #999999;
$palette-davysGray: #555555;
$palette-white: #ffffff;
$palette-carbon: #333333;
$palette-blueFire: #00ace5;
```

How can I sort it in hexadecimal color code order?

(I know you can use `:sort x` to reorder the hexadecimal numbers. But it doesn't work if there's another string before the hexadecimal number, as in this example.)

Answer (score 3):

try looking at the help pages in vim. `:h sort`tells you that you can specify a pattern.`:sort / /` should do the trick.

from help sort:

```
text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so 
you sort on what comes after the match.
```

Comment: You don't need such a complicated pattern, `/#/` is enough. Or `/:/`, or even `/ /`.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I have a new problem.

``.
#ccc
#000
#202020
#fff
#00ace5
````

What if I also have a mixed color code that is represented by 3 characters?

Comment: @dadchyyy you should open a new question for that. I would try to expand `ccc -> 0c0c0c`

Comment: @dadchyyy I would appreciate it, if you could accept my answer.